# Shiny R - download the result of a table

Tags: r, download, shiny

I am new to Shiny and I have created a really simple shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(7,dataTableOutput('dto')))
)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$dto <- renderDataTable({MYTABLE})


}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Is there any way to put an option to download the result of the table (doesn't matter if is CSV, XLSX...)

cheers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's pretty easy with `downloadButton()` or `downloadLink()` in combination with `downloadHandler` if you make the data itself a reactive expression. Then you can download whatever you send to output using the same reactive expression.

A small example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # This one is linked by the id 'download'
  downloadButton('download',"Download the data"),
  fluidRow(column(7,dataTableOutput('dto')))
)

server <- function(input,output){
  # Reactive expression with the data, in this case iris
  thedata <- reactive(iris)

  output$dto <- renderDataTable({thedata()})
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){"thename.csv"}, 
    content = function(fname){
      write.csv(thedata(), fname)
    }
  )

}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Keep in mind:

- the argument `content` of `downloadHandler` must be a function producing a file! It should take one argument for the connection/file name. In this example it is a csv file, but for eg images you can use `png()` and `dev.off()`, for ggplots you can use `ggsave()`, ...
- the argument `filename` does not have to be a function, but I found it works
  better that way. Especially when working with reactive expressions for the file name.
- you link the `downloadHandler` and the `downloadButton` through the output list: the id of `downloadButton` is the name of the output element returned by `downloadHandler`.

EDIT:

Some people try to use `download.file()` for this, but that's wrong as well. The function `download.file()` works when used on the user side, not the server side. It lets you download files from the internet to the computer that is calling the function. If you'd use that in a Shiny application, it would work when run locally. That's because user and server are the same machine. However, when deploying your app on a Shiny Server, `download.file()` would essentially be downloading files TO the server, not from.

Comment: sometimes I've personally had issues using `write.csv()` when writing some tables to output for downloads and have switched to using ` content = function(file) {
        write.table(downloadInput(), file, sep = ",",
                    row.names = FALSE)
      }`

Comment: @Phi weird, as `write.csv` is nothing else but a wrapper around `write.table`. It's not even a different method. I know S3 dispatching can sometimes go wrong with shiny, but that can't be the issue here. If you have an example, I'm very interested to take a look at it.

Comment: i will have to look to find a case where the error occurred but i can tell you it was in saving a data.table created from a mysql query and using the future package

Comment: I am a little late to the party, but could someone tell me what iris is? How might i get my actual data from a tableoutput to populate the csv?

Comment: @CU_dev `iris` is a built in dataset in R that's often used in examples. Replace `iris` with your own dataset and you should be good.

Answer (score 14):

A slightly alternative solution based directly on the `datatable` / `DT` extension `buttons`.

I am shamelessly borrowing the example data from Joris...

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
 # This one is linked by the id 'download'
  fluidRow(column(7,dataTableOutput('dto')))
)

server <- function(input,output){
  # Reactive expression with the data, in this case iris
  thedata <- reactive(iris)

#the extensions parameter coupled with the options list does the trick  
output$dto <- renderDataTable(thedata(), extensions = 'Buttons', 
                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))
  )
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser=TRUE) #now runs by default in the external browser.
```

This will work with different outputs and personally I like the cleaner look. Just make sure that you are running the demo in the external browser. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have checked, and the options of CSV and PDF doesn't worked to me.

Comment: @jmarco10 Did you run it in the external browser? I have made a change to the code, so that it runs automatically in the browser `runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server),launch.browser = T)`

Comment: @user3293236 no prob, and thanks for adding the DT way. I shamelessly edited your code to write `TRUE` in full :-P Seriously though, try: `a <- matrix(c(0,1),ncol=2); T <- t(a)` and run your code again. That's enough reason to write `TRUE` in full, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: I am a little late to the party, but could someone tell me what iris is? How might i get my actual data from a tableoutput to populate the csv?

Comment: @CU_dev Iris is a famous test data set. The data comes with R. Try data(iris) to load it in your current session. For using your own data, replace the line thedata <- reactive(iris) with your source data frame

Comment: I think solution above exports to excel only those rows visualized by the user and not the entire table

Answer (score 1):

I have to execute the app in the browser because the filename isn't working. I use

`runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server),launch.browser = T)`

and it works perfectly for me.

If you don't want to use `launch.browser=TRUE` you can write the filename and the extension for example .csv at the end of the filename when you use the download button in the shiny app.