# How can I use the buttons extension in DT to download this table?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

Below is the portion of code I'm having trouble with. There is a drop down on the page that allows the user to select between two different tables being pulled from a database. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to download. As you can see in the code, I initially attempted to use downloadLink but I'm wondering if the buttons extension of DT would be better suited. Either way, I can't get it work. Any ideas?

```
                #Results Tab UI
                 tabPanel(
                    "Study Results",
                    br(),
                    selectInput("resultsDisplay", "Display results by", choices = c("Single Study", "Compare Studies")),
                    uiOutput("resultsPnoDropUI"),
                    selectInput("resultsType", "Results Type", choices = c("results_mn", "results_pairwise")),

                    downloadLink("downloadResults", "Download this File"),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("studyResultsTable")

                )

    )
})

#Search and User ID Database Connections
protocolDB <-dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "clin_oral.db")


resultsDB <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "OralCareResults.sqlite")
results_mn <- dbReadTable(resultsDB, "Means")
pairTable <- dbReadTable(resultsDB, "Pairwise")

#Results DT Output
output$studyResultsTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    resultTable <-if(is.null(input$resultsType))
        return()

    dat<- get(input$resultsType)
})
```

Comment: Have you tried with the methods described in these resources? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504759/shiny-r-download-the-result-of-a-table

Comment: I have. The problem I'm running into with that is no matter what I put in, I get an error saying function not found. I have a feeling it's because of the way the drop down is set up and there not being one dataset in the table, but rather what data is displayed is dependent on the input.