# add shiny selections to table which can be exported

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have the following app which I created with some help from stack overflow

I want to be able to pick the practice for each doctor, then create a table based on the user input, then be able to export that table.

The app needs to adjust for a variable amount of doctors each time (the real app pulls from a dynamic database with new docs being added daily), hence the renderUI with conditional panels

I am having trouble passing selections from the practice into a table which I can render and export.

Any help much appreciated.

Here is my reprex

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

find_docs <- dplyr::tibble(record = c("joe", "mary", "dan", "suzie"))
locs_locs <- dplyr::tibble(record = c("practice1", "practice2", "practice3"))

mytable <- dplyr::tibble(
          doc = find_docs$record, 
          location = rep("", length(find_docs$record))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
          #numericInput("num_selected", label = "Fields to Display", value = 0, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1),
          uiOutput("condPanels"), 
          tableOutput(outputId = "mydt")
)

server<-function(input,output,session){
          
          
          
          output$condPanels <- renderUI({
                    # if selected value = 0 dont create a condPanel,...
                   # if(!input$num_selected) return(NULL)
                    tagList(
                              lapply(head(find_docs$record), function(nr){
                                        conditionalPanel(
                                                  condition = paste0("Find DOC", nr),
                                                  fluidRow(
                                                            column(3, 
                                                                   tags$br(),
                                                                   nr
                                                                   
                                                                   ), 
                                                            column(3, selectInput(paste0("DOC", nr), "pick loc", 
                                                                                  choices = locs_locs))
                                                  )
                                                  
                                        )
                              })
                    ) 
          })
          
          output$mydt <- renderTable({
                    #somehow i need to use mytable here

                    z <- data.frame( g = rep(input$find_docs$record[1], length(find_docs$record)))
                    z
                    
                    # i want to render a table of find_docs in one column, and the selections in a second column)
                    # then i want to be able to export the table as csv
                    
                    
          })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to capture your two needs. First, I took the inputs from each of the select inputs to create the table. I used lapply to pass each of the doctors to the input name. Then I combined this with the doctor list to create a data frame and a table.

I used the package DT for the second part of your request, to be able to download. DT has an extension which has a really easy way to download files in different ways. Hopefully this helps, good luck!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT) #Added DT to download the table easily

find_docs <- dplyr::tibble(record = c("joe", "mary", "dan", "suzie"))
locs_locs <- dplyr::tibble(record = c("practice1", "practice2", "practice3"))

mytable <- dplyr::tibble(
  doc = find_docs$record, 
  location = rep("", length(find_docs$record))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("condPanels"), 
  DTOutput(outputId = "mydt")
)

server<-function(input,output,session){
  
  
  
  output$condPanels <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      lapply(head(find_docs$record), function(nr){
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = paste0("Find DOC", nr),
          fluidRow(
            column(3, 
                   tags$br(),
                   nr
                   
            ), 
            column(3, selectInput(paste0("DOC", nr), "pick loc", 
                                  choices = locs_locs))
          )
          
        )
      })
    ) 
  })
  
  output$mydt <- renderDT({
    #An error will occur without this as it's trying to pull before these inputs are rendered
    req(input[[paste0("DOC",find_docs$record[1])]]) 
    
    z<-lapply(find_docs$record, function(x){
      input[[paste0("DOC",x)]]
    }) #Grab each of the inputs 
    
    z2 <- data.frame("DOC" = find_docs$record, "LOC" = unlist(z)) #Combine into a data frame
    z2
    
  }, extensions = "Buttons", #Using the extension addon of DT to have options to download the table
  options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                 buttons = c('csv')) #Download types
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

If you didn't want to use DT, you could also put the table into a reactiveValue, and then download it using the download button. Both of these download options are visible on this other page I just realized: [Shiny R - download the result of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504759/shiny-r-download-the-result-of-a-table)

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING! many thank yous, I will do a deep dive to see just how you did it