# How can I add a download csv button from a reactive renderTable() in shiny?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, reactive, flexdashboard

I am brand new to shiny apps in R. I have made a working reactive dashboard with the final output being a table created using `renderTable()`. The current markdown file is as follows:

````
---
title: "Dashboard Test"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    css: style/style.css
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)


species_data <- read.csv("./species_data.csv")



Dashboard Test
=====================================


Inputs {.sidebar data-width=250}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<h3>Dashboard Test</h3>

Use the Search Bar to select your species of interest. Trait data will update to suit your selection.
&nbsp;  
&nbsp;  
<h3>Species</h3>
{r}
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "sp_search", 
        label = "",
        multiple = TRUE,
        choices = unique(species_data$Species),
        options = list(
          create = FALSE,
          placeholder = "Search",
          onDropdownOpen = I("function($dropdown) {if (!this.lastQuery.length) {this.close(); this.settings.openOnFocus = false;}}"),
          onType = I("function (str) {if (str === \"\") {this.close();}}"),
          onItemAdd = I("function() {this.close();}")
        )
      )


Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
&nbsp;  
{r}

# create reactive output that is dependent on what is selected within the search bar
output <- reactive(species_data %>% filter(Species %in% input$sp_search))

# display table with selected species                   
renderTable(output())
````

I would simply like a "download" button that, when clicked, downloads a .csv file of `renderTable(output())`. Others have asked similar questions but with largely different dashboard styles. Since I am new to shiny I am unsure of the syntax used to incorporate this kind of dashboard feature. Any help appreciated. Data is confidential so unfortunately unable to share.

The following does not work:

```
renderDataTable(output(), extensions = 'Buttons',
                buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))
```

Comment: If you use the data table package, you could use `renderDT(…, extensions = “buttons”, buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', …)` to provide some downloadable options (or just buttons = “csv” for csv only)

Comment: Also, this might answer your question: [Shiny R - download the result of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504759/shiny-r-download-the-result-of-a-table)

Comment: @jpsmith Yes, have seen those responses to similar questions, but unsure where to place within the rmd. At the end?